# Compilation Error in Xcode 4.3 but building in Xcode 3

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xcode4.2

I recently migrated from Xcode 3.2 to Xcode 4.3 , 
some projects are getting build successfully but in one of the project, i am getting compilation error,

Both the error are present in  spotlight importer.

while compiling main.c

'**CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h' file not found**

and in the file  GetMetaDataForFile

**'CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h' file not found**

```
File Name : main.c it was inside "importer" folder, 
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <CoreFoundation/CFPlugInCOM.h>
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

File Name : GetMetaDataForFile.c

#include "CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

#import "MySpotlightImporter.h"
```

Comment: Can you post the #include lines from that file?   It looks like it might be related to the paths changing between 3.2 (/Developer) and 4.3 (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer).  In which case, the compiler might not be looking in the right place.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking ^^ try deleting reference to, and reading your frameworks.

Comment: @gaige, if this is the issue, it should come from other system header too ? it looks like, only CoreFundation is giving problem.

Comment: You probably should have consistent use of your <> and "", but you may also need to go through your build instructions looking for anything named path and make sure you didn't inadvertently remove a DEVELOPER_DIR path that would be in the defaults.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.What should i do?

Comment: It's happening only when i connecting through a device(iPod 4th Gen iOS 5.1.1).

Comment: Happens for me as well. Fresh install of OS X 10.7.4, fresh install of Xcode, checked the box for installing updates automatically.